# How to create a Read only Address group in iPad Programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, abaddressbook

I was able to create a group in contacts from my app. But when the user opens the Contact app and view my group he is able to edit the contacts that was saved. I was wondering if it is possible to make a groups and contact programatically and make this groups and contact as read only once opened from Contact app.
The facebook app is importing and saving the contacts in similar fashion.

Any thought on this is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: ContactApp is a builtin app. You can't set permissions on it through your app.

Comment: @NabeelThobani I want to set the permission of contacts created from my app to be read only when it is viewed from contact app . Like facebook does